# Instagram Real time updates tag - callback called twice?

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am using instagram real time updates for tag, to get notification when someone tag media with specific tag. Subscription works fine, and im able to check subscription directly using 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret={cs}&client_id={cid}

Within callback i have something like

```
if (isset ($_GET['hub_challenge'])){
    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}
else{
    $my_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $sub_update = json_decode($my_string);
    //do the rest of the things with data we fetched
}
```

}

But, this callback is executed twice from instagram side. So for example, if i subscribe to "winter" tag, and if someone publish media and tag it using that tag, instagram will send notification twice to callback file i specified during subscription (both calls are executed within few secs). Why instagram sending request twice to the callback? Anyone had similar issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After debugging and investigation i found that call is sent from instagram twice if callback file is not executed fast enough.

Based on the [documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/?hl=en):

> Also, you should acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout--if
>   you need to do more processing of the received information, you can do
>   so in an asynchronous task.

They will send second request in case they dont receive response on first request within 2 secs.

At the end, i had blank callback.php file with only "sleep" inside it and its called twice each time.

Comment: Providing that quote you probably saved my day. In current docs version, it's missing and it's not clear why notifications are send twice. Going to check out.