# why is Instagram real-time API POSTing 2x for each tag subscription event?

Tags: instagram-api

The Instagram Real-Time API POST updates my subscribed node server twice for each 'tag' event. What can I do on my server side and/or in my Instagram API settings to receive only one notification per subscribed event?

(This problem has been raised on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380741/instagram-real-time-updates-tag-callback-called-twice), but the respondent did not describe their steps clearly enough for me to apply in my case.)

Comment: what are you using? PHP? AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Instagram real-time API docs, [a response to the POST is required](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#receiving-updates) (within 2 secs) and my server omitted a response!